# How to Create a R TimeSeries for Hourly data

Tags: r

I have hourly snapshot of an event starting from 2012-05-15-0700 to 2013-05-17-1800. How can I create a Timeseries on this data and perform HoltWinters to it?

I tried the following

```
EventData<-ts(Eventmatrix$X20030,start=c(2012,5,15),frequency=8000) 
HoltWinters(EventData)
```

But I got Error in decompose(ts(x[1L:wind], start = start(x), frequency = f), seasonal) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

What value should I put from Frequency?

Comment: This [post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/) and this [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/123010/46401) by Hyndman explains which frequency you should choose.  Instead of using `xts` as suggested by @dickoa, you can also use the `msts` function/object from the`forecast`package, with the added benefit, that it allows you to specify multiple seasons/cycles. The package also includes a function `hw` which is convenient wrapper function for `forecast(ets(...))`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you should consider using `ets` from the package `forecast` to perform exponential smoothing. Read [this post](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/estimation2/) to have a comparison between `HoltWinters` and `ets` .

```
require(xts)
require(forecast)

time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2012-05-15 07:00"), 
                  to = as.POSIXct("2012-05-17 18:00"), by = "hour")
set.seed(1)
value <- rnorm(n = length(time_index))

eventdata <- xts(value, order.by = time_index)
ets(eventdata)
```

Now if you want to know more about the syntax of `ets` check the help of this function and the online book of Rob Hyndman ([Chap 7 section 6](http://otexts.com/fpp/7/6/))

Comment: thanks, but suppose I want to create a TimeSeries using the tf function, for this hourly data, how to proceed. Sorry I am a R newb.

Comment: @DotDot `xts` extend the `ts` class and every function which works with `ts` works with regular `xts` object. So basically, there's no need to use `ts` for hourly data. The packages `zoo` or `timeSeries` can be used too to create hourly time series.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the following post which might answer the question:

[Decompose xts hourly time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583944/decompose-xts-hourly-time-series/31586363#31586363)

Its explains how you can create a xts object using POSIXct objects. This xts object can have its frequency attribute set manually and you will probably then be able to use HoltWinters

Comment: This should be a comment!

Comment: @PareshMayani this poster doesn't have enough reputation to comment. Samy, link-only answers are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Could you edit your answer to include the details from the linked answer that clarify how it could be used for this question?

Comment: @josilber yup agree! I was about to post another comment but then lost the connection! Thanks for putting down a helpful comment.