# How to decompose xts half hourly time-series data

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have the dataset below with half hourly timeseries data.

```
Date <- c("2018-01-01 08:00:00", "2018-01-01 08:30:00", 
          "2018-01-01 08:59:59","2018-01-01 09:29:59")
Volume <- c(195, 188, 345, 123)
Dataset <- data.frame(Date, Volume)
```

I convert to Date format with:

```
Dataset$Date <- as.POSIXct(Dataset$Date)
```

Create xts object

```
library(xts)
Dataset.xts <- xts(Dataset$Volume, order.by=Dataset$Date)
```

When I try to decompose it based on [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583944/decompose-xts-hourly-time-series) with:

```
attr(Dataset.xts, 'frequency')<- 48
decompose(ts(Dataset.xts, frequency = 48))
```

I get:

```
Error in decompose(ts(Dataset.xts, frequency = 48)) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

Comment: The question you link to uses `as.ts` not `ts` in the decompose.

Comment: I know but this in not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments you need `as.ts` instead of `ts`. Also you are specifying a frequency higher than the number of records you have. Both lead to errors.

**This code works:**

```
library(xts)

df1 <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-01 08:00:00", "2018-01-01 08:30:00", 
                                          "2018-01-01 08:59:59","2018-01-01 09:29:59")),
                      volume =  c(195, 188, 345, 123))

df1_xts <- xts(df1$volume, order.by = df1$date)

attr(df1_xts, 'frequency') <- 2
decompose(as.ts(df1_xts))
```

**This doesn't** (frequency higher than number of records):

```
attr(df1_xts, 'frequency') <- 48
decompose(as.ts(df1_xts))
Error in decompose(as.ts(df1_xts)) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

**Neither does this** (`ts` instead of `as.ts`):

```
attr(df1_xts, 'frequency') <- 2
decompose(ts(df1_xts))
Error in decompose(ts(df1_xts)) : 
  time series has no or less than 2 periods
```